# Copy text and preserve formatting from Microsoft Word to Excel using C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, rtf

I am currently working on a project that converts a test from a "standard" word format to a format that is accepted by the new Saras program we are using.

I have been able to parse the file and gather the information that I want. Unfortunately there is a problem with the formatting, I only know how to parse and insert plain text.

A few options I have found so far include using the .Copy() method and then using the .Paste() method on the cell. I am using a class to hold the data intermittently so that if another parsing algorithm needs to be used for the next person's "standard" format, then the data will still be able to be put into the excel document the same way and the developer only needs to worry about parsing the new format.

NOTE: If there is a way to paste this into a format (like a stand alone cell) and then set the cell or cell value to it, that would be great.

Another option that I have found is using the interop.word.range.formattedtext property. This would work well if I was going to go from one word document to another, but I need to somehow get this formatted text over to an excel cell.

My current thought process would be to take the text and put it into a RTF object. Later I would take it and put it into excel by inserting the RTF.text into the cell and use the RTF.format to format each character. This seems like more work than I should have to do.

Please let me know what you all come up with!

Here is some code:

STORAGE:

```
class Question
{
    public string text;
    private List<string> responses;

    public Question(string txt, List<string> r)
    {
        text = txt;
        responses = r;
    }
    public List<string> getResponses() { return responses; }
}
```

PARSING:

```
if (p < MAX && docs.Paragraphs[p].Range.ListFormat.ListValue != 0)
{
    // question main line
    qTxt = docs.Paragraphs[p].Range.Text.ToString();
    p++;
    // question pos responses NOTE: THIS WILL BE USED TO DO MULTIPLE CHOICE LATER
    for (; p < MAX && docs.Paragraphs[p].Range.ListFormat.ListValue == 0; p++)
    {
        tmp = docs.Paragraphs[p].Range.Text.ToString();
        if (tmp != null && tmp != "\r")
            qTxt += " \r\n " + docs.Paragraphs[p].Range.Text.ToString();
    }
}
```

SET THE VALUE:

```
foreach (Question question in questionList)
{
    ...
    // ITEM TEXT
    ws.Cells[row, 15].Value2 = question.text;
    ...
}
```

Again, this code works for setting plain text, I just want to know how to get the formatting in there as well.

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:
I figured out a way to make the Copy and Paste work. Silly me, I can just keep the excel document open the entire time. The constructor now sets up the first row and the parseDocument function will then fill in the rows with the data.

THE STRUGGLE:
I am currently using the Copy and Paste functions, but it seems to be putting an image of the text into my document rather than the formatted text itself.

CODE:

```
// Get the title
Word.Range rng = docs.Paragraphs[p].Range.Duplicate;
int index = 0;
for (; p < MAX && docs.Paragraphs[p].Range.ListFormat.ListValue == 0; p++)
{
    string tmp = docs.Paragraphs[p].Range.Text.ToString();
    if (tmp != null && tmp != "\r")
        ++index;
}
rng.MoveEnd(Word.WdUnits.wdParagraph, index);
rng.Copy();
xlDoc.ws.Range["A1", "A1"].PasteSpecial(); // Pastes an image of the title
```

Alas, I am looking for any way around this possible. Please let me know if you have any solutions.

Thanks!!

PS. I will keep updating this post if I make any progress.

Comment: Alas, as of 2015-09-16 I have not found an answer and decided to move on with the program using plain text. If someone answers it may help future endeavors, but this program will use a plain text version of the original.

Comment: This project has been terminated but I will leave up the question in case anyone can find this useful.